# Coda slider from within Tabbed Ajax?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

in this page: http://www.studiokhalid.com/test/jquery/2.html

I am trying to use a simple Jquery Coda slider (that works fine alone) inside the OUTDOOR tab in the Jquery Tools Tabbed Ajax. When I click that tab, it is empty ! while it actually display the Coda slider.

Help is very much appreciated, and thanx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a guess, but it probably isn't loading the ajax content, but since you didn't include your javascript, it is difficult to say.

Edit:
Thanks for adding your example.  The problem is actually quite simple to fix.  Your script is doing the AJAX stuff alright.  However, your css file has set the content it loads to not display.

in your tabs-no-images.css file around line 60:

```
.css-panes div {
   ...
   display:none;
   ...
}
```

That *display:none;* is your culprit.

Comment: Thanx revil, for other tabs pointing to pages with textual content it works fine.

Comment: Excellent and very well spotted revil !! Many thanx

I still have something wrong though - the Coda slider actually does not work properly. So my question is, where should I put the header calls for the Coda slider?

Sorry I am not that good with java.

Thanks revil

Comment: website updated to show the current problem - slider not loading.

Comment: OK! I see what is going on now.  I think...  I am guessing that display:none was on purpose.  The coda-slider script would un-hide things when needed.  but this is just a guess.  you didn't include the script for the coda slider in your code!

Comment: The coda slider is in "ajax1.htm" which is called by the first tab. I am sure the way I am including it is not right, but I have no clue as how to correctly get things in place. thanx

Comment: you are including the html, not the js in ajax1.htm  however, i did notice going directly to ajax1.htm, it works.  when you include ajax1.htm in to your 2.html file, it is only grabbing the information located in the <body> tag of ajax1.htm.  this means your js scripts in ajax1.htm is never loaded.  just move those in to the <body> tag.